# SQL Developer - How to join to another table if output from first join is null?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's the situation. I've got 1 table of inventory (inv), and I want to join it together with the table for inbound shipments (inb), on the value shipment_id that is stored in both tables.
In the 'inb' table the value 'origin' is stored, and for each record in the 'inv' table I want to know what that 'origin' is. Below is an example:

```
SELECT
  invent.item_id,
  invent.location_id,
  invent.quantity,
  inbound.origin
FROM    
  inventory invent
LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments inbound
  ON invent.shipment_id = inbound.shipment_id
```

But some shipments are not in the inbound_shipments table anymore and have been moved to inbound_shipments_archive.
Given: For every shipment_id there's a record in either the inbound_shipments table or the inbound_shipments_archive table, so if the value returned in the joined column is null, it must be in the other table.

**My question is: How can I make this join in a way where it will get the desired value ('origin') from one of these 2 tables into the same column?**

I've tried joining both tables with the columns next to each other. This worked and is an okay alternative if there's no other option

```
SELECT
  invent.item_id,
  invent.location_id,
  invent.quantity,
  inbound.origin,
  inboundarch.origin
FROM
  inventory invent
LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments inbound
  ON invent.shipment_id = inbound.shipment_id
LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments_archive inboundarch
  ON invent.shipment_id = inboundarch.shipment_id
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I completely acknowledge that this is well outside the scope of your inquiry, but I would question the value of a database design that moves rows to an "archive" table on the same database, especially when it's clear you're still interested in their contents. I would be very curious to understand the requirement that gave rise to this.

Comment: @esqew I understand your concern, the reason for this is that both the regular shipment table and the archive shipment table can be queried from the GUI by the front-end users. If a shipment is complete, it will be moved to the archive table after 3 months. Front-end users rarely need to see shipments 3 months after completion, so having all of these in a different table makes performing queries for shipments in the regular table much faster. I'm one of the few users that actually needs the archive tables to create analyses and reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87) to return the value from the main shipments table if there is one, or from the archive table if not:

> `COALESCE` returns the first non-null *expr* in the expression list. You must specify at least two expressions. If all occurrences of *expr* evaluate to null, then the function returns null.

So rather than having the columns from both tables in the select list, replace those with the result of `COALESCE`, and (optionally) give that column expression an alias:

```
SELECT
  invent.item_id,
  invent.location_id,
  invent.quantity,
  COALESCE(inbound.origin, inboundarch.origin) AS origin
FROM
  inventory invent
LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments inbound
  ON invent.shipment_id = inbound.shipment_id
LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments_archive inboundarch
  ON invent.shipment_id = inboundarch.shipment_id
```

This doesn't need a CTE or inline view, or a `UNION`.

As you only have two value you could also use [`NVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html#GUID-3AB61E54-9201-4D6A-B48A-79F4C4A034B2), but `COALESCE` is more standard.

Comment: Thank you, this solution was the easiest for me and also used the least code. Looks great and works great.

Answer (score 2):

A "clean" way to do this would be to [`UNION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE) `inbound_shipments` and `inbound_shipments_archive` in [a CTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html) and `JOIN` to that:

```
WITH inbound_shipments_combined AS
(
    SELECT * FROM inbound_shipments
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM inbound_shipments_archive
)
SELECT
    invent.item_id,
    invent.location_id,
    invent.quantity,
    inbound.origin
FROM    
    inventory invent
    LEFT JOIN inbound_shipments_combined inbound on invent.shipment_id = inbound.shipment_id
```

The example above assumes `inbound_shipments` and `inbound_shipments_archive` have the same schema - it's still possible to `UNION` them if they don't, but you'd have to be very deliberate about the fields you select from each of the component tables in the CTE.

Comment: If I understand the design correctly, a row will either be found in one table or the other, never in both. It will suffice hence to apply `UNION ALL` here and safe the DBMS the work to look out for duplicates with `UNION [DISTINCT]`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I do agree with you, and I waffled between including the example of `UNION ALL` and simply `UNION`. A little voice in the back of my head wondered about something of a "race condition" (dependent on how the archival mechanism is designed) where a row could potentially be present in both tables at runtime. In practice, since this is unlikely to happen, I'd agree a more performant version of this would use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! @ThorstenKettner I also tried the same query but with UNION ALL. My query is quite small so in this case the difference in speed was negligible, but I will keep this in mind for bigger queries or frequently scheduled queries.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have two tables: one for regular inbound shipments ('inbound_shipments') and another for archived inbound shipments ('inbound_shipments_archive'). You also have an 'inventory' table.

You want to find out where each item in your inventory came from, either from the regular shipments or the archived ones. If a shipment is not in the regular table, it might be in the archived table.

Here's how you can do it:

For each item in your inventory, you can check both the regular shipments and the archived shipments. If the item is in the regular shipments, great! If not, you check the archived shipments. If the item is in the archived shipments, that's where it came from.

In SQL, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    invent.item_id,
    invent.location_id,
    invent.quantity,
    COALESCE(inbound.origin, inboundarch.origin) AS origin
FROM
    inventory invent
LEFT JOIN
    inbound_shipments inbound ON invent.shipment_id = inbound.shipment_id
LEFT JOIN
    inbound_shipments_archive inboundarch ON invent.shipment_id = inboundarch.shipment_id;
```

The COALESCE function helps pick the origin from either the regular shipments or the archived shipments, depending on where the information is available.